# Dirichlet Green's function outside the sphere

Tags: greens-function, dirichlet-character, mirror-symmetry

I am trying to find the Dirichlet Green's function for the spherical region centred at 0 and of radius a. I have found the Dirichlet Green's function inside the sphere by method of images, but what is the Green's function outside the sphere? (I think it should be the same but I'm not sure if I'm correct.)
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $\frac{-1}{4\pi|x-x_0|}$ + $\frac{a}{4\pi|x-x_1||x_0|}$, where $x_1$ is $\frac{a^2x_0}{|x_0|^2}$ @Gonçalo